# Bundling and Minification Issue in Chrome but works fine in Mozilla

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have few JS files which i am trying to Bundle using MVC4, the code is as follows:-

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //Global App Items go here.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/modernizr")
        .Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lib")
        .Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/bootstrap")
        .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css"));

    var lessBundle = new Bundle("~/content/myApp").Include(
        "~/Content/jqueryMultiSelect.less",                
        "~/Content/scrollbars.css");
    lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
    lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
    bundles.Add(lessBundle);

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Now, when i see my `console` in Firefox, I can see my Response as Expected. But when same i do it in Chrome, the bundled file is broken.

Broken may be a non-technical term, What i mean by broken is :-
[image]

The file is incomplete....

Please let me know, if i need to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually the display issue.

In chrome the js file length is limited, so does not display completely.

Try to open that file in a new tab, you will see the entire content.

In Firefox, it prompts the user to open in a new tab to see the complete content.